# Getting Labels a name with a label

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

This panel class is suppose to print out "Course Info" Yet when I do try to print it out on the GUI, the gui frame shows up but not the Panel. So I feel the panel code is the problem, how to get the "Course Info" to appear? And if the label is working correctly, why when I post the label to the gui, it just shows another blank Frame?

Panel:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class TopPanel extends JPanel {

    public TopPanel(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(Crse);

    }
}
```

GUI code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CourseGUI extends JFrame {
    public CourseGUI()
    {

        super("CourseGUI Frame");


        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(java.awt.Color.WHITE);
        Dimension d = new Dimension(800,600);

        topPanel.setPreferredSize(d);

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setSize(800,600);
        //JPanel tp = new TopPanel();
        //this.add(tp.BorderLayout.North);


        JPanel panel = new TopPanel();
       this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new CourseGUI();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
 public TopPanel(){     
        JLabel Crse = new JLabel("Course Info");
        Crse.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        add(Crse);
    }
```

You are creating new `JPanel` which will not going to get added in `JFrame`.

As you are doing this.

```
this.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

for `JFrame` but `topPanel` don't have anything to display because you didn't add anything.